# Login a user from code with claims authentication (fba)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

i have a problem with logging in a user from server side on a claims (fba) enabled site.
Users can register themselves on the site and get an email with a confirmation link.
After they click on the confirmation link, they should be automatically logged in.

My first attempt was to log in with the authentication web service (_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx), get the cookie and add it to the page response.
Unfortunaly the authentication web service returns a System.Net.Cookie instead of System.Web.Httpcookie.

Is this the right path?
Is there another way?

Thanks for your help!

**[Update]**

Creating a Httpcookie out of the System.Net.Cookie and add this to the page response did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(
                Context.Request.UrlReferrer,
                UserName.Text, 
                Password.Text);
```